# Checking every element in an array for a specific requirement

Tags: python, arrays, loops, iteration

I need to check every element in an array to see if it can be divided by 5 or more different numbers, if not - drop it into a different array.

For example, I have an array [3,32,6,8,0,16,3,45] and I have to get a result of [3,5,8,0,3]

I tried going for a simple while loop inside a for loop:

```
for i in array:
    n = 0
    div = 1
    while n <= 4 and div <= i:
        if i % div == 0:
            n += 1
        div += 1

    if n <= 4:
        sub_array.append(i)

return sub_array
```

It works just fine, but I need to make it so it will check the division with elements and not indexes. The moment I change all 'i' to 'array[i]': "list index out of range". Is there any way to solve this issue?
The reason why I'm trying to improve this code is because the tester I am using to check it returns errors from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `for i in array` it means the 'i' is the element in the array.
If you want to iterate with using `array[i]` you should use `for i in range(len(array))`

The modified code is as follows:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    n = 0
    div = 1
    while n <= 4 and div <= array[i]:
        if array[i] % div == 0:
            n += 1
        div += 1

    if n <= 4:
        sub_array.append(array[i])

return sub_array
```

Comment: did as you said before, but it does not give me the desired result: out of an array [3,32,6,8,0,16,3,45] i must get [3,6,8,0,3], but i receive [0, 2, 3, 4, 6]

Comment: Look at the added code please.

Comment: okay, sorry, it looks like it was a bug on my side, now works all right

Answer (score 0):

I've written this code for you (if any of the numbers from an array is not divisible by 5, they will be put into a different array):

```
array = [3,32,6,8,0,16,3,45]
subarray = []
for i in array:
    if i%5==0:
        continue
    else:
        subarray.append(i)

print(subarray)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but already solved, and the issue was to check every array element to see if it can be divided by different numbers more than 4 times, if not - save it

Comment: most welcome mate! I'm happy that your issue has been solved